# How to Synchronize function calls with callbacks?

Tags: c++, api, callback, synchronization

I am using a SDK that provides some functions and one callback to send the results. Code is in C++.

SDK APIs:

```
typedef void(*onSdkCallBackFn)(int cmdType, const char *jsonResult);
void SetCallback(onSdkIotCallBackFn Fn);
void SetCommand(int commandId);
```

There is no return value for SetCommand, so need to wait for SDK to send the result through callback.

I need to provide my own API for upper layer, but they expect to get the result by function call and do not intend to receive it through callback.
here is my sample code:

```
void MyCallback(int cmdType, const char *jsonResult)
{
  int result;
  if (cmfType == 5)
    result = 100;
  else
    result = 0;
}
    
int DoCommandNo5()
{
  int result = -1;  // need to be updated in callback function
  etCallback(&MyCallback);
  DoCommand(5);
  // here I need to wait for result through SDK callback and return it.
  // How to handle it?
  return result; 
}
```

Can I do this without using threads? What is the best way to handle this task?

I checked these approaches: WaitForSingleObject and std::condition_variable but seems for both need create separate thread.

Any advise and help is appreciated.

Comment: Presumably the sdk is using threads? The synchronisation primitives you've found are probably exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Is the callback called while `DoCommand()` is running? Or is it called asynchronously after `DoCommand()` exits?

Comment: It is called  asynchronously after DoCommand() exits  @RemyLebeau
Actually it is because this SDK need to handle communication with WiFi devices and it takes some time to get response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one way to do it is to e.g. wait on `std::condition_variable`:

```
int DoCommandNo5()
{
    int result = -1;
    bool resultReady = false;
    std::mutex m;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    std::condition_variable cv;
    
    auto getResult = [&](int commandResult) {
        resultReady = true;
        result = commandResult;
        cv.notify_one();
    };
    
    setCallback(getResult);
    doCommand(5);
    cv.wait(lk, [&]{return resultReady;});
    
    return result;
}
```

You can also call `cv.wait_for` method so `DoCommandNo5` function doesn't block infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Since the details are vague, I will answer from a very general perspective of how to wrap an event driven based functionality into a standard function.

I expect result to be accessible globally or passed somehow to the callback function. Therefore, in the function expecting the callback to set an actual result, one can just do waiting while loop. e.g.:

```
int result;

void TheCallback() {
  ...
  result = 255;
  ...
}

int TheCallbackWrapper() {
  ...
  result = -1; // let's assume -1 means result is not yet set
  while (result == -1) {
    sleep(1); // an assumption of system call to sleep the execution for 1 ms, just not to eat CPU time too much
  }
  return result; // if we reach this point, then the callback has set a result ready to be returned
}
```

Comment: The loop blocks the calling thread, so this approach only works if the callback is called in another thread.

Comment: I have modified my post to become clear what I need.